# How to create a message box with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I've been trying to build a fairly simple message box in tkinter that has "YES" and "NO" buttons. When I push the "YES" button internally it must go and write YES to a file. Similarly, when "NO" is pushed, NO must be written to a file. How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like a good homework question to me... So, what do you have so far?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the module [tkMessageBox](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/dialogs.html#tkMessageBox) for Python 2.7 or the corresponding version for Python 3 called `tkinter.messagebox`.

It looks like `askquestion()` is exactly the function that you want. It will even return the string `"yes"` or `"no"` for you.

Comment: The tkinter.messagebox does not work in my ubuntu 12.04 python

Comment: @Ajoy Check which version of Python you have, you might need to do `tkMessageBox` if it's 2.x.

Answer (score 13):

Here's how you can ask a question using a message box in Python 2.7. You need specifically the module `tkMessageBox`.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


root = Tk().withdraw()  # hiding the main window
var = tkMessageBox.askyesno("Title", "Your question goes here?")

filename = "log.txt"

f = open(filename, "w")
f.write(str(var))
print str(var) + " has been written to the file " + filename
f.close()
```

Comment: Link to the othe types of message boxes http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html

Answer (score 8):

You can assign the return value of the `askquestion` function to a variable, and then you simply write the variable to a file:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

variable = messagebox.askquestion('title','question')

with open('myfile.extension', 'w') as file: # option 'a' to append
    file.write(variable + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `message box` from Tkinter using

```
# For python 3 or above
from tkinter import messagebox

# For python less than 3
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
```

Here's the basic syntax:

```
messagebox.Function_Name(title, message [, options])
```

**The message boxes are modal and will return a subset of (True, False, OK, None, Yes, No) based on the user’s selection.**

So to get the value of message box you just need to store the value in a variable. An example is given below:

```
res=mb.askquestion('Exit Application', 'Do you really want to exit')
if res == 'yes' :
    root.destroy()
```

There are different type of message boxes or Function_name:

1. showinfo(): Show some relevant information to the user.
2. showwarning(): Display the warning to the user.
3. showerror(): Display the error message to the user.
4. askquestion(): Ask question and user has to answered in yes or no.
5. askokcancel(): Confirm the user’s action regarding some application activity.
6. askyesno(): User can answer in yes or no for some action.
7. askretrycancel(): Ask the user about doing a particular task again or not.
8. Message: creates a default information box, or is same as showinfo box.

```
messagebox.Message(master=None, **options)
# Create a default information message box.
```

You can even pass your own title, message and even modify the button text in it.

Things you can pass in the message boz:

- title: This parameter is a string which is shown as a title of a message box.
- message: This parameter is the string to be displayed as a message on the message box.
- options: There are two options that can be used are:

  1. default: This option is used to specify the default button like ABORT, RETRY, or IGNORE in the message box.
  2. parent: This option is used to specify the window on top of which the message box is to be displayed.

Links i have used for this answer:

- [Message box tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-messagebox-widget/amp/)
- [Message box documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any other modules to do this!

```
>>> from tkinter import messagebox
>>> messagebox.askokcancel("Title", "Message")
True
```

It returns True when the ok/retry/yes button is pressed, and False otherwise.

Other available ones:

- askokcancel()
- askyesno() or askquestion() (same)
- askretrycancel()