# Get rid of toplevel tk panewindow while usong tkMessageBox

Tags: python, tkinter

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052420/tkkinter-message-box)

When I do :

```
tkMessageBox.askquestion(title="Symbol Display",message="Is the symbol visible on the console")
```

along with Symbol Display window tk window is also coming.

If i press "Yes"...the child window return yes,whereas tk window remains there.

Whenever I am tryng to close tk window, End Program - tk comes. on pushing "End Now" button "pythonw.exe" window comes asking to send error report or not.

Why is it so ?
How can I avoid tk window from popping out without affecting my script execution ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *trick* is to invoke withdraw on the Tk root top-level:

```
>>> import tkMessageBox, Tkinter
>>> Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
>>> tkMessageBox.askquestion(
...     title="Symbol Display",
...     message="Is the symbol visible on the console")
```