# Displaying message in messagebox Tkinter from variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to display some value from variable in message box using Python for example following is my code and I have to display the values of a and b on message box so what should I do?

```
import tkinter as tk
a="hello"
b="how are you"
tk.messagebox.showinfo("info name",a,b)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a message box with tkinter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052420/how-to-create-a-message-box-with-tkinter)

Comment: Just concatenate the variables and pass it into the second parameter of `showinfo()`. e.g. `tk.messagebox.showinfo("info name", a + b)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want to do, combine a and b into one different variable.

```
c = a + " " + b
```

`.showinfo()` takes 2 arguments, so combine the two into one.
The complete code would be:

```
import tkinter as tk
a = "hello"
b = "how are you"
c = a + " " + b
tk.messagebox.showinfo("info name", c)
```

Hope I helped! -Me!

EDIT: If you want to skip a line replace `c = a + " " + b` with `c = a + "\n" + b`

ANOTHER EDIT: If you need to use numbers, use `"x"` instead of regular `x` when x is the number. Example:

```
a = "2"
b = "3"
```

Comment: Thanx it helped me

Comment: @shivleen Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

`.showinfo()` takes 2 arguments.

You can also use the following method to achieve the same result and avoid the creation of new variable.

```
import tkinter as tk
a = "hello"
b = "how are you"

tk.messagebox.showinfo("info name", a + " " + b)
```